# preloading big images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, preload

So I have this problem, there are really large images (7MB) which I need to display as backgrounds and stuff, but when online the browser just take a moment and display the images slowly (like its 2001).

Is there a way to get some sort of preloader, like in flash, but with jQuery? I've seen tons of stuff but that's doesnt seem to be actual preloading, but bringing in images on the fly.

is there a way I can do this?

Comment: why aren't your images optimized for the web?

Comment: basically I didn't made the images, a client provided the images and I'm more a programmer than a designer...

Comment: It's probably easier to research how to optimize images - and better for your users (something programmers, designers, and clients should care about)

Comment: any good links on the subject?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-images-for-the-web-with-photoshop/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it,but there is a jquery plugin that can help,Lazy Load

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to optimize these images for the web. That being said, there are ways you can preload them. I would definitely only load them when you need them so you could try storing the image urls somewhere then when needed do something like:

```
var myImageUrl='image.jpg';
$('.imageContainer').append('<img src="'+myImageUrl+'" />');
$('.imageContainer img').load(function() {
    alert('done loading image');
});
```

With this you can create a pre-loader.